# jqxDateTimeInput with WebForms

Tags: jquery-ui

Does anyone know how to use jq widgets ui for a basic date with a server control event?

I am new with Jquery UI and trying to learn how to implement with web forms

Answer (score 0):

Ajax call can be used to pass the values of the jqxDateTimeInput to the server side.